# Basic Auth Spring security with enum Roles and Permissions always return 401

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

i am new to Spring Security, i just have a User with enum Role and enum permissions, i wanted to have a basic auth using postman and to test it , but i always get 401 status code.
I am not sure what is the problem exactly because no errors i receive or no exeption occured but all i know is that i can not log in with basic auth using postman perhaps my configuration is not perfect or UserDetails and UserDetailsServices are not like they should be or maybe capturing the authorities in UserDetails is not working at all.
or maybe my password is not encoded in database and that's why the authentication can not pass.

My ApplicationSecurityConfig:

```
`@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

//private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
private final ApplicationUserDetailsService applicationUserDetailsService;

@Autowired
public ApplicationSecurityConfig(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, 
ApplicationUserDetailsService applicationUserDetailsService) {
   // this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    this.applicationUserDetailsService = applicationUserDetailsService;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http

            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/index","/css/*","/js/*")  .permitAll()

            //MEMBER
            .antMatchers("/api/**").hasAnyRole(
                    ApplicationUserRole.SUPER_ADMIN.name(),
                    ApplicationUserRole.ADMIN.name(),
                    ApplicationUserRole.MEMBER.name()

            )
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/api/**").hasAnyAuthority(
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.SUPER_ADMIN_READ.name(),
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.ADMIN_READ.name(),
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.MEMBER_READ.name()
            )

           //ADMIN
            .antMatchers("/admin/api/**").hasAnyRole(ApplicationUserRole.ADMIN.name(),ApplicationUserRole.SUPER_ADMIN.name())
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/admin/api/**").hasAnyAuthority(
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.SUPER_ADMIN_WRITE.name(),
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.ADMIN_WRITE.name()
            )
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/admin/api/**").hasAnyAuthority(
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.SUPER_ADMIN_WRITE.name(),
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.ADMIN_WRITE.name()
            )
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH,"/admin/api/**").hasAnyAuthority(
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.SUPER_ADMIN_WRITE.name(),
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.ADMIN_WRITE.name()
            )
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/admin/api/**").hasAnyAuthority(
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.SUPER_ADMIN_WRITE.name(),
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.ADMIN_WRITE.name()
            )

            //SUPER_ADMIN
            .antMatchers("/super/admin/api/**").hasAnyRole(
                    ApplicationUserRole.SUPER_ADMIN.name()
            )
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/super/admin/api/**").hasAuthority(
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.SUPER_ADMIN_WRITE.name()
            )
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/super/admin/api/**").hasAuthority(
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.SUPER_ADMIN_WRITE.name()
            )
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH,"/super/admin/api/**").hasAuthority(
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.SUPER_ADMIN_WRITE.name()
            )
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/super/admin/api/**").hasAuthority(
                    ApplicationUserPermissions.SUPER_ADMIN_WRITE.name()
            )

            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();



}


@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(applicationUserDetailsService);
}`
```

ApplicationUserRole:

1. package com.github.workTimeMangementGithub.security;

   ```
   import com.google.common.collect.Sets; import
   org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority; import
   org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

   import java.util.Set; import java.util.stream.Collectors;

   public enum ApplicationUserRole {
       SUPER_ADMIN(Sets.newHashSet(ApplicationUserPermissions.SUPER_ADMIN_READ,ApplicationUserPermissions.SUPER_ADMIN_WRITE)),
       ADMIN(Sets.newHashSet(ApplicationUserPermissions.ADMIN_READ,ApplicationUserPermissions.ADMIN_WRITE)),
       MEMBER(Sets.newHashSet(ApplicationUserPermissions.MEMBER_READ,ApplicationUserPermissions.MEMBER_WRITE));

       private final Set<ApplicationUserPermissions> permissions;

       ApplicationUserRole(Set<ApplicationUserPermissions> permissions) {
           this.permissions = permissions;
       }

       public Set<ApplicationUserPermissions> getPermissions() {
           return permissions;
       }


       public Set<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities() {
           Set<GrantedAuthority> permissions = getPermissions().stream().map(permission-> new
   SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.getPermission())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
           permissions.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+this.name()));
           return permissions;
       }

   }
   ```

Here i have implemented User Role for Role Based Auth and i connect them with their permissions

My ApplicationUserPermissions

```
public enum ApplicationUserPermissions {

    SUPER_ADMIN_WRITE("super_admin:write"),
    SUPER_ADMIN_READ("super_admin:read"),
    ADMIN_WRITE("admin:write"),
    ADMIN_READ("admin:read"),
    MEMBER_WRITE("member:write"),
    MEMBER_READ("member:read");


    private final String permission;

    ApplicationUserPermissions(String permission) {
        this.permission = permission;
    }

    public String getPermission() {
        return permission;
    }

}
```

Here i Created the permissions for every User Role to determine all permissions and privileges for each role.

My ApplicationUserDetailsService

```
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
@Slf4j
public class ApplicationUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {


    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<User> user  = Optional.of(userRepository.findUserByUsername(username));
        if(user.get() != null){
            UserDTO userDto = UserMapper.toDTO(user.get());
            log.info("User Found   "+ userDto.getUsername());
        }else {
            log.warn("User NOT Found   ");
        }
        user.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found: " + username));
        return new ApplicationUserDetails(user.get());
    }


}
```

Here i have implemented ApplicationUserDetailsService and called the method loadUserByUsername with handling UserNotFoundException in case the user is not found.

My ApplicationUserDetails:

```
@Slf4j
public class ApplicationUserDetails implements UserDetails {

    private  List<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities;
    private  String username;
    private  String password;
    private  boolean isAccountNonExpired;
    private  boolean isAccountNonLocked;
    private  boolean isCredentialsNonExpired;
    private  boolean isEnabled;

    public ApplicationUserDetails(List<? extends GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities, String username, String password, boolean isAccountNonExpired, boolean isAccountNonLocked, boolean isCredentialsNonExpired, boolean isEnabled) {
        this.grantedAuthorities = grantedAuthorities;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.isAccountNonExpired = isAccountNonExpired;
        this.isAccountNonLocked = isAccountNonLocked;
        this.isCredentialsNonExpired = isCredentialsNonExpired;
        this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
    }

    public ApplicationUserDetails(User user) {
        List<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>(ApplicationUserRole.ADMIN.getGrantedAuthorities());
        this.grantedAuthorities = authorities;
        log.warn("authorities  "+authorities);
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.isAccountNonExpired = true;
        this.isAccountNonLocked = true;
        this.isCredentialsNonExpired = true;
        this.isEnabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return isAccountNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return isAccountNonLocked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return isCredentialsNonExpired;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return isEnabled;
    }
```

Here i have implemented ApplicationUserDetails and override some methods.

My problem is that i can not authenticate using basic auth via Postman.

Here a screen capture of the users of the database:
[image]

I am trying to find out what is wrong with my code , i follow many tutorials but no full example of working with enum Roles and permissions with JPA authentication , i spend a lot of time and i still don't know what is wrong exactly with my code.
The logger Slf4j is no showing the authenticated user in console and i don't know why.
Postman:
[image]

Spring Boot log Captures:

[image]

Any help will be so appreciated.

Comment: And your spring security debug logs say?

Comment: nothing except hibernate user select query but nothing after it and the log do not show if the user is found or not. i added a screen capture

Comment: `ApplicationUserPermissions.SUPER_ADMIN_WRITE.name()` isn't the same as `ApplicationUserPermissions.getPermission`. The latter is what is getting added to the collection of roles/authorities, instead of the `name()` of the enum. That will thus never match.

Comment: Thank you for your comment , but im not sure that i understand , do you propose to delete .getPermission() and replace it by .getName() ? im sorry are you speaking about that syntax in AntMatchers?or in GrantedAuthorities?

Comment: A log never says nothing, i asked because i wanted to see your logs, not you explaining your intepretation of the logs

Comment: It was not showing anything before i enable Spring security debug

Comment: The screenshot of the logs is not very helpful, unfortunately. There are a number of things going on that make it difficult to debug. The security configuration indeed looks incorrect as @M.Deinum points out. You want to use `ApplicationUserPermissions.ADMIN_WRITE.getPermission()` instead of `.name()`, etc. It also looks like you're creating all your users with `ApplicationUserRole.ADMIN`. Can you provide a GitHub repo with this sample code, it might help if we can check out the source code and suggest improvements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment , i will try change User Role , if it will not work i will push to github and send the repository URL